# Data Driven Pages reading angles in attribute tables question

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

Is there a way to emulate the Data Driven Pages process (ArcGIS 10) of reading angles (rotation) in a polygon shape file? [Screen shot of the DDP window with rotation field and corresponding attribute circled in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w84j5.png)

In other words, make a polygon rectangle shp recognize an "Angle" field from its attribute table and automatically rotate the polygon rectangle based on that "Angle" field ?

Comment: How was your Angle field populated? http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/40888-how-do-you-calculate-rotation-angle-for-data-driven-pages

Comment: it's all Esri-automated as far as i can tell with Data Driven Page's "Strip Map Index Features" function (in ArcToolbox > Cartography Tools > ddp)... i usually run this tool based on a long polyline and the attribute table always has the angle field populated in the new mapbook shp file it creates.

Comment: Seems i could better formulated this question, that esri forum "It's much harder than that!" link is not really helping much... i will post question again without using Data Driven Pages as a reference for what i am trying to do, if mods think that is okay?

Comment: FOUND SOLUTION http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=210244 will need to download EasyCalculat10 here:http://www.ian-ko.com/free/EC10/EC10_download.htm

Answer (score 1):

The asker of this Question has not logged into the site for 6 months but it looks like he/she was satisfied with the answer found at the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=987&t=210244)**:

> You can use the field calculator with
>   "polygon_rotate_byFieldValues.cal" expression of
>   EasyCalculate(http://www.ian-ko.com). It will rotate the polygons with
>   an angle from a field. The rotation point is the centroid of each
>   polygon.  You'll need to do some changes (rotation field) in the code.